# Why is the commutator expressed as $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ instead of $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$?

Tags: group-theory, notation

In almost all texts I am finding the definition

> The commutator of $a,b \in G$ is the element $$aba^{-1}b^{-1}$$

However, it seems more intuitive to me to define it as

> The commutator of $a,b \in G$ is the element $$a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$$

Because we can just interchange $a$ with $a^{-1}$ freely, since they are just labelings. For example, we could define $+1$ to be the action of $a$, hence $-1$ is the action of $a^{-1}$ or visa versa w.l.o.g.

The reason why I feel that the second one is more intuitive is because you just pick a pair $a,b$. You then 'do' $b$, then 'do' $a$, then 'undo' $b$ then 'undo'  $a$, which seems more natural than the other way around.

Is there a specific reason why the commutator is defined in this sense, or have I just got it all wrong.

The same question I guess applies to conjugation, where $g^{-1}hg$ seems more natural than the usual $ghg^{-1}$.

For example, I see conjugation as this

> 1. Move the object
> 2. Do something to the object
> 3. Put the object back where it was originally

Which would correspond more naturally to $g^{-1}hg$.

Comment: If I had to guess, people like to put the higher powers first, generally. Compare $ax^2+bx+c$ with $a+bx+cx^2$. (Even there, the reverse convention seems to be more logical, since infinite series are written $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dotsb$.)

Comment: Of course, $ab$ "doing $b$ then $a$" is true for *left* actions; for right actions the reverse is true.

Comment: For conjugation, the fact that with $c_g(h) = ghg^{-1}$ we have $c_{ab} = c_a \circ c_b$ is a pretty good argument for that convention, IMO.

Comment: you could use $hg^{-1}h^{-1}g$ I suppose

Comment: I think it is very common for group theorists to use the $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$ version.

Comment: $g^{-1}hg$ is the image of a right action of $g$ on $h$, whereas $ghg^{-1}$ comes from a left action. So if you prefer right actions, then use $g^{-1}hg$ and $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$, and for left actions use $ghg^{-1}$ and $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$. It might be true that group theorists prefer right actions whereas most other species favour acting on the left.