group commutator can take $[a,b]=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$ or $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ - which convention should I take along with left group action convention?

The above picture from this groupprops page suggests that $(a,b)\mapsto aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ (resp. $(a,b)\mapsto a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$) is typically combined with the left (resp. right) action convention. I don't know any natural left or right group action that involves commutators.
Similar problem happened in conjugation but in that case $(g,h)\mapsto ghg^{-1}$ (resp. $(h,g)\mapsto g^{-1}hg$) is a left (resp. right) group action.

Update: One group action that involves commutator is following: $G$ acts on the set of commutators by conjugation, but it doesn't help, because it is a left or right action only depends on how we define conjugation, but not how we define commutators.

A duplicate question currently without answer is this question on MathStackExchange, thansks to the comment. One of the comment there suggests that if you prefer left group action, then conjugation should be $(g,h)\mapsto ghg^{-1}$ (with the reason just like above) and the commutator should be $(a,b)\mapsto aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ (without a convincing reason).
It might use the idea that the left-group-action version of conjugation puts inverse on the right hand side, so the left-group-action version of commutators should do the same. I am personally not really convinced by it.

The question is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531887/why-is-the-commutator-expressed-as-aba-1b-1-instead-of-a-1b-1ab but I cannot mark it as a duplicate because there the people have (again) ignored the site guidelines and posted their answers in the comment section.

Personally, I will prefer $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$. When $G$ is a Lie group, this definition of commutator matches the definition of commutator $[a,b] = ab - ba$ for corresponding Lie algebra.

@achillehui This match only convinces me that $[a,b]$ should not be $b^{-1}a^{-1}ba$ or $bab^{-1}a^{-1}$ which I already accept by considering the oders of $a$ and $b$. Also $ab-ba=(-ba)+ab$.

I have a motivation now: the left-group-action version of commutator should be $(a,b)\mapsto a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$.
Because one of the results about commutators is that for any normal subgroup $H$ of $G$ that contains $[G,G]$, $G/H$ (which is the left cosets, compatible with left group action) is abelian, i.e. $aH*bH=abH=baH=bH*aH$, which is equivalent to $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab\in H$ or equivalent to $b^{-1}a^{-1}ba\in H$. Among these two choices we of course choose $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$.
